# Sum based on a given criteria

Tags: r, loops

I have the following data set :

```
Min Max PFQty   SFQty
800 900 0      0
800 900 0   0
800 900 30  30
800 1000    0   0
800 1000    42  42
900 1000    0   0
900 1000    0   0
900 1000    150 150
900 1000    0   0
900 1000    0   0
900 1000    0   0
900 1000    40  40
900 1000    14  14
900 1000    28  28
900 1000    14  14
900 1000    56  56
900 1000    120 120
900 1000    60  60
900 1000    1512    1512
900 1000    1096    1096
900 1100    24  24
1000    1100    9   9
1000    1100    60  60
1000    1100    250 250
1000    1100    435 435
```

I need to sum columns `PFQty` only till the difference between columns `Min` and `Max` is 100 . If it exceeds 100 then I need to ignore those rows.

Comment: Maybe `sum(mydf[ mydf$Max - mydf$Min <= 100, "PFQty"])` ?

Comment: No the resultant is a sum of all the places where the difference is 100. Instead I need a total between 800-900,900-1000,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr, filter, then group by and sum:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(Max - Min <= 100) %>% 
  group_by(Min, Max) %>% 
  summarise(PFQtySum = sum(PFQty))

#     Min   Max PFQtySum
#   <int> <int>    <int>
# 1   800   900       30
# 2   900  1000     3090
# 3  1000  1100      754
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Max  - Min <= 100, .(PFQtySum = sum(PFQty)) , by =  .(Min, Max)]
#    Min  Max PFQtySum
#1:  800  900       30
#2:  900 1000     3090
#3: 1000 1100      754
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create another column

```
 data$diff<-abs(data$min-data$max)
```

then it would be easy

```
sum(data[diff<=100,]$PFQty)
```

Is it doing what you need?

Comment: I had already done that but the resultant will not what I want. I need the data to be split into class intervals & the corresponding sum beside say 800-900  30 900-1000 3090 ...

Comment: so you want to class the differences and then sum the column based on the value of the difference ?